# “convert_values_to_string” or “convert_values_to_strings”

Tags: grammar

In the end, each value will be a string.

I’m always confused.

Should I use “convert_values_to_string” or “convert_values_to_strings”.

NOTE: The values are stored in an `array`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the naming of functions and variables is [**explicitly off-topic**](/help/on-topic). If you would like to convert this to a question about the English language, it will probably be possible to make it on-topic.

Comment: Also note that the first variable name in the title is different to that in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either one works. If you say *convert values to string*, it will be understood to mean *string form*.